# Unmet dependencies for libopencv

Tags: upgrade, dpkg, dependencies, opencv

I tried to upgrade to ubuntu 20 but the process somehow got stuck in the middle. Now I am finding it difficult to get back my system to normal as everything I install meets with the same output. For example, when I tried to install OpenCV I encountered the following error

```
You might want to run 'apt --fix-broken install' to correct these.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
libopencv-contrib-dev : Depends: libopencv-calib3d-dev (= 4.2.0+dfsg-5)
                     Depends: libopencv-core-dev (= 4.2.0+dfsg-5)
                     Depends: libopencv-dnn-dev (= 4.2.0+dfsg-5) but it is not going to be installed
                     Depends: libopencv-features2d-dev (= 4.2.0+dfsg-5)
                     Depends: libopencv-flann-dev (= 4.2.0+dfsg-5)
                     Depends: libopencv-highgui-dev (= 4.2.0+dfsg-5)
                     Depends: libopencv-imgcodecs-dev (= 4.2.0+dfsg-5)
                     Depends: libopencv-imgproc-dev (= 4.2.0+dfsg-5)
                     Depends: libopencv-ml-dev (= 4.2.0+dfsg-5)
                     Depends: libopencv-objdetect-dev (= 4.2.0+dfsg-5)
                     Depends: libopencv-photo-dev (= 4.2.0+dfsg-5)
                     Depends: libopencv-stitching-dev (= 4.2.0+dfsg-5)
                     Depends: libopencv-video-dev (= 4.2.0+dfsg-5)
                     Depends: libopencv-videoio-dev (= 4.2.0+dfsg-5)
libopencv-shape-dev : Depends: libopencv-video-dev (= 4.2.0+dfsg-5)
libopencv-superres-dev : Depends: libopencv-video-dev (= 4.2.0+dfsg-5)
                      Depends: libopencv-videoio-dev (= 4.2.0+dfsg-5)
libopencv-videostab-dev : Depends: libopencv-calib3d-dev (= 4.2.0+dfsg-5)
                       Depends: libopencv-photo-dev (= 4.2.0+dfsg-5)
                       Depends: libopencv-video-dev (= 4.2.0+dfsg-5)
libopencv-viz-dev : Depends: libopencv-core-dev (= 4.2.0+dfsg-5)
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt --fix-broken install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

Even when I try `sudo apt upgrade` or  `sudo apt install -f` i am facing the same error. I just don't know how to get rid of this.

I have looked into the following [issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28454724/ubuntu-14-04-apt-get-libopencv-dev-but-get-errors-unable-to-correct-problems) but no help to my question.

Comment: https://vitux.com/opencv_ubuntu/

Comment: "*I tried to upgrade to ubuntu 20 but the process somehow got stuck in the middle*" This suggests a serious problem with your system that should be investigated and fixed before worrying about specific applications. Failures during a release-upgrade may require a reinstall.

Comment: Upgrade Ubuntu Core 20 to what?